# Ember.js 2.7 does not build using yarn - does build using npm

Tags: node.js, ember.js, yarnpkg

**Versions:**

- ember.js 2.7, ember-data 2.7
- ember-cli 2.9.1 // true for ember-cli 2.7 as well
- node 6.9.1, npm 3.10.9 // true for node 4.4.4 and npm 2.15.5 as well
- Mac El Capitan

**Steps to reproduce:**

- `rm -Rf node_modules bower_components`
- `yarn`
- `bower install`
- `ember s` or `ember build`

**Symptoms:**

---

```
Build failed.
The Broccoli Plugin: 

[Funnel: Funnel
  vendor/ember-cli-qunit/images
  /assets
 include:2] failed with:

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir '/Users/somePath/client/tmp/funnel-input_base_path-nIg5n9K9.tmp/0/vendor/ember-cli-qunit/images/'
    at Error (native)
    at Object.fs.readdirSync (fs.js:951:18)
    at FSMonitor._measure (/Users/somePath/client/node_modules/heimdalljs-fs-monitor/index.js:66:21)
    at Object.readdirSync (/Users/somePath/client/node_modules/heimdalljs-fs-monitor/index.js:82:30)
    at _walkSync (/Users/somePath/client/node_modules/broccoli-funnel/node_modules/walk-sync/index.js:64:18)
    at Function.entries (/Users/somePath/client/node_modules/broccoli-funnel/node_modules/walk-sync/index.js:40:10)
    at Funnel.processFilters (/Users/somePath/client/node_modules/broccoli-funnel/index.js:264:26)
    at Funnel.build (/Users/somePath/client/node_modules/broccoli-funnel/index.js:202:10)
    at /Users/somePath/client/node_modules/broccoli-plugin/read_compat.js:61:34
    at tryCatch (/Users/somePath/client/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:538:12)

The broccoli plugin was instantiated at:
    at Funnel.Plugin (/Users/somePath/client/node_modules/broccoli-plugin/index.js:7:31)
    at new Funnel (/Users/somePath/client/node_modules/broccoli-funnel/index.js:56:10)
    at /Users/somePath/client/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/broccoli/ember-app.js:1474:12
    at Array.map (native)
    at EmberApp.otherAssets (/Users/somePath/client/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/broccoli/ember-app.js:1468:61)
    at EmberApp.toArray (/Users/somePath/client/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/broccoli/ember-app.js:1642:10)
    at EmberApp.toTree (/Users/somePath/client/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/broccoli/ember-app.js:1662:30)
    at module.exports (/Users/somePath/client/ember-cli-build.js:67:16)
    at CoreObject.setupBroccoliBuilder (/Users/somePath/client/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/models/builder.js:70:19)
    at CoreObject.init (/Users/somePath/client/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/models/builder.js:50:10)
```

---

If I do an `npm install` after yarn, the console output is:

---

```
npm WARN prefer global jshint@2.9.4 should be installed with -g
npm WARN prefer global marked@0.3.6 should be installed with -g
npm WARN prefer global node-gyp@3.3.1 should be installed with -g

> node-sass@3.10.1 install /Users/somePath/client/node_modules/node-sass
> node scripts/install.js


> node-sass@3.10.1 postinstall /Users/somePath/client/node_modules/node-sass
> node scripts/build.js

"/Users/somePath/client/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/darwin-x64-46/binding.node" exists.
 testing binary.
Binary is fine; exiting.
npm WARN prefer global npm@3.10.9 should be installed with -g

> spawn-sync@1.0.15 postinstall /Users/somePathclient/node_modules/spawn-sync
> node postinstall

auth0-ember-simple-auth@1.1.0 node_modules/auth0-ember-simple-auth
```

---

If I `rm -Rf node_modules` and do a standard `npm install`, the build works without errors like all the time before.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE: Diff of node_modules folders built by `npm install` and `yarn`:**

---

Only in yarn_node_modules/: .yarn-integrity

Only in yarn_node_modules/: ansi

Only in yarn_node_modules/: ansistyles

Only in yarn_node_modules/: archy

Only in yarn_node_modules/: async-some

Only in yarn_node_modules/: builtins

Only in yarn_node_modules/: char-spinner

Only in yarn_node_modules/: chmodr

Only in yarn_node_modules/: chownr

Only in yarn_node_modules/: cmd-shim

Only in yarn_node_modules/: columnify

Only in yarn_node_modules/: config-chain

Only in yarn_node_modules/: debuglog

Only in yarn_node_modules/: defaults

Only in yarn_node_modules/: dezalgo

Only in yarn_node_modules/: dom-storage

Only in yarn_node_modules/: editor

Only in yarn_node_modules/: esprima

Only in yarn_node_modules/: fs-vacuum

Only in yarn_node_modules/: fs-write-stream-atomic

Only in yarn_node_modules/: fstream-ignore

Only in yarn_node_modules/: fstream-npm

Only in yarn_node_modules/: github-url-from-git

Only in yarn_node_modules/: github-url-from-username-repo

Only in yarn_node_modules/: ic-ajax

Only in yarn_node_modules/: iferr

Only in yarn_node_modules/: init-package-json

Only in yarn_node_modules/: jju

Only in yarn_node_modules/: json-parse-helpfulerror

Only in yarn_node_modules/: lockfile

Only in yarn_node_modules/: lodash.pad

Only in yarn_node_modules/: lodash.padend

Only in yarn_node_modules/: lodash.padstart

Only in yarn_node_modules/: normalize-git-url

Only in yarn_node_modules/: npm-cache-filename

Only in yarn_node_modules/: npm-install-checks

Only in yarn_node_modules/: npm-registry-client

Only in yarn_node_modules/: npm-user-validate

Only in yarn_node_modules/: opener

Only in yarn_node_modules/: path-is-inside

Only in yarn_node_modules/: promzard

Only in yarn_node_modules/: proto-list

Only in yarn_node_modules/: read

Only in yarn_node_modules/: read-installed

Only in yarn_node_modules/: read-package-json

Only in yarn_node_modules/: readdir-scoped-modules

Only in yarn_node_modules/: realize-package-specifier

Only in yarn_node_modules/: retry

Only in yarn_node_modules/: sha

Only in yarn_node_modules/: sigmund

Only in yarn_node_modules/: sorted-object

Only in yarn_node_modules/: text-table

Only in yarn_node_modules/: uid-number

Only in yarn_node_modules/: umask

Only in yarn_node_modules/: validate-npm-package-name

Only in yarn_node_modules/: wcwidth

---

Comment: I compared the npm_modules folders built by npm install and built by yarn with simple `diff -q`. See updated post.

Answer (score 1):

Yarn removes a lot of pieces of packages by default during its cleanup phase. Ember-cli-qunit requires the images directory to run, but it is removed by default.

Update your **.yarnclean** file and replace the line:

> images

with

> !images

This will leave all images directories, you can refine the regexp if you need more specificity.

Comment: The thing I don't understand is why others are not having this problem. There should be a lot of yarn and ember-cli users hitting this issue.

Comment: The .yarnclean file only gets created if you explicitly run `yarn clean`

Comment: @shawnn42 I think that needs to be 'yarn autoclean --init'.

Comment: @Bracke at the time of writing that comment, yarn clean would also add that file (without explicitly asking for it) I'm not sure if that is still the case.

Comment: @shawnn42 It did not create it when I tried, with autoclean it did create the file. I can't even find the 'clean' command on https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/
Looks like they have removed it??

Answer (score 0):

I'm running into the same thing. I found another workaround to be downgrading ember-cli-qunit back to v1.4.0 also allows the modules to be built with yarn.